# grep: "^." doesn't match correctly

Tags: regex, posix, grep

Can someone explain why this code doesn't work as expected?
I would expect it only to match the first character, and it does with literal characters, but the wildcard (.) and characters classes behave strangely:

I use -o just to demonstrate exactly how things are matching, it doesn't change what matches at all.

```
$ echo foo | grep -o '^.'
f
o
o
```

Some more unexpected behavior:

```
$ echo foobarbazquux | grep -o '^[foarqux]'
f
o
o

$ echo foobarbazquux | grep -o '^.[^u]'
fo
ob
ar
ba
zq
```

Esentially the beginning-of-line matcher (^) is not behaving as expected in these cases. Is there any way to make it behave more normally?

Comment: Is it really working wrong if you don't use -o? My guess is that -o output may be produced before applying anchors.

Comment: I see the exact same behavior with GNU grep 2.5.1. It's as if grep is restarting the search after each match. Another test case: `echo foobarfoo | egrep -o 'foo|^bar'` displays `foo`, `bar`, `foo`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I could reproduce this behavior on my OSX terminal with grep 2.5.1. Even more mysteriously, `$` works as expected -- just not `^`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it:

[Bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?11579)

[Changelog of fix](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/grep/ChangeLog?root=grep&r1=1.279&r2=1.280)

Apparently fixed in 2.5.2. Found it via launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

From my Ubuntu 10.04 box:

```
marc@panic:~$ echo foo | grep -o '^.'
f
marc@panic:~$ echo foobarbazquux | grep -o '^[foarqux]'
f
marc@panic:~$ echo foobarbazquux | grep -o '^.[^u]'
fo
marc@panic:~$ grep --version
GNU grep 2.5.4
```

There are a series of environment variables grep will look for to control its behavior/output, so check if any of those are set. Most likely you've got 'GREP_OPTIONS' set.

Comment: 2.5.1 here, behaves like bukzor's, see my comment to the question.

Comment: I get the same behavior as OP even if I use `env -i` to clear out the environment.